# What's the best way to express concept requirements for data members in a concept?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

what's the best way to define a concept with a nested concept requirements for a data member of the type? Something along these lines:

```
template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires(T a) {    
    {a.something} -> std::integral;
};
```

This doesn't work because `a.something` is picked up as a reference (`delctype((a.something))`). The best I came up with that works is something like this that forces an rvalue:

```
constexpr auto copy = [](auto value) { return value; };

template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires(T a) {    
    {copy(a.something)} -> std::integral;
};
```

Do I have any better options?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The downside of `copy` is that it can create false positives for you. A reference member will decay to a value. The only way to ensure the actual type of the member is analyzed, is to write an explicit nested requirement.

```
template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires(T a) {    
    requires std::integral<decltype(a.something)>;
};
```

Comment: What about just `template<typename T> concept MyConcept = std::is_integral_v<decltype( T().something )>;`? Does the `T()` cause any issues or does this amount to the same?

Comment: @non-user38741 - It checks more than just the member access. You sneaked the ability to value initialize `T` into there (and being able to destroy the temporary, but that's less of an issue). `std::declval` was created to avoid the problem, but honestly, the requires expression syntax is just way more readable.

Comment: Right. Looking for the simplest version, what about leaving out the second `requires`?Seems fine to me.

Comment: @non-user38741 - Then it no longer checks that `a.something` is of an integral type. It doesn't verify the `std::integral` concept is satisfied. All if checks is that `std::integral<decltype(a.something)>` is a valid expression. So it will fail if `T` doesn't have `something` at all, but it will pass even if `something` is not an integer type.

Comment: Now, that's surprising, but right again, thanks. Always have to be on guard.

Answer (score 0):

For cases like this, it'd be pretty easy to create a concept specifically for references to integral:

```
template<typename T>
concept integral_ref = std::is_reference_v<T> && std::integral<std::remove_reference_t<T>>;
```

You can then use `integral_ref` directly.

Indeed, you can even create generic a `reference_trait` that works for any unary, boolean type traits that expect object types:

```
template<typename T, template<typename> class Trait>
concept reference_trait = std::is_reference_v<T> && Trait<std::remove_reference_t<T>>::value;

template<typename T>
concept MyConcept = requires(T a) {    
    {a.something} -> reference_trait<std::is_integral>;
};
```

Comment: In my case I really wanted to check it's a plain integral value. If I use your solution I won't distinguish between `int something` and `int& something`.

Comment: @dcmm88: Why should you care? If the user of your interface wants to have a reference member, why should that matter to you or any code you write with respect to your concept? Don't be so controlling over the user's implementation.

Comment: In my use case I need the struct to be trivially copyable.

Comment: @dcmm88: Then `is_trivially_copyable_v` should be part of your requirements at some point. And you would be stopping it, not because it has a reference member, but because it isn't trivially copyable. This would also catch other things that prevent trivial copyability.

Comment: Sure, in my own use case I do have the requirement of trivially copyable, but I didn't included in my question because  originally I didn't think it's relevant. Still, you can see how your suggested solution would be a bit odd for my use case. Going through all the trouble to deal with references when I don't even want those to be allowed.